# Jquery conflict with jquery tools

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is after adding:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

to my site, Plugins like nivoslider, and other jquery scripts are not working.

but in order to make working the code below i need "jquery tools"

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function GetAvailProductSizes() {
        $('select#productsize option').remove();
        $('select#productsize').append('<option value=""><? echo $langdata['oneprodpage_selectsize']; ?>...</option>');

        var color = $('#productcolor').val();
        if (color > 0) {
            var availsizes;
            var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            http_request.open( "GET", '<? echo ROOT; ?>/autocompleteavailsizes/?productid=<? echo $thisproduct['id']; ?>&color=' + color, true );
            http_request.send(null);
            http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if ( http_request.readyState == 4 ) {
                    if ( http_request.status == 200 ) {
                        availsizes = eval( "(" + http_request.responseText + ")" );

                        for (var i = 0; i < availsizes.length; i++) {
                            $('select#productsize').append('<option value="' + availsizes[i].id + '">' + availsizes[i].name + '</option>');
                        };
                    } else {
                        alert( "There was a problem with the URL." );
                    }
                    http_request = null;
                }
            };
        };
    }
//-->
</script>
```

it works only if i include:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

BUT if i do so, other jquery scripts are not working, i mean nivoslider and other simple popup divs...

How should i solve this problem?

Comment: OMG! Alert the press! THE CODE IS NOT WORKING! It's likely that you are including multiple jQuery libraries or that you have included them in the wrong order or that you need to use http://api.jquery.com/noConflict. It's hard to know for sure because you didn't provide us with enough information.

Comment: No need to shout! Your original post included "I get this error:" and it looked like someting was missing.

Comment: Well, about other information. This code is not distarbing my site, or other codes. the problem is with Jquery.tools.min.js. After i include it, the code above works, but nivo slider doesnt

Comment: -1 Please provide details and update your question

Comment: Felix, by error i was meaning that other jwuery plugins arnt working after adding Jquery.tools.min.js

Comment: Are there errors in your console? Are you including a different version of jQuery along with this? I bet it is a version conflict.

Comment: jquery tools includes it's own version of jQuery. Include a version of jQuery tools that doesn't include it's own jQuery. `http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/all/jquery.tools.min.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Tools includes it's own version of jQuery. Include a version of jQuery tools that doesn't include it's own jQuery. `http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/all/jquery.tools.min.js`

Make sure you include your other jquery first, followed by jquery tools, and then the rest.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="nivoslider.js"></script>
...
```

Comment: if i add this "http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/all/jquery.tools.min.js"

Comment: it only works with "http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"

Comment: It will if you correctly order your includes and include a version of jQuery that works both with jquery tools and your other scripts.

Comment: Again, as has been asked MANY times. What error are you getting? "It doesn't work" doesn't mean anything to us.

Comment: No errors, I answered few times. 

JQuery order: 1. jquery-1.7.1.min.js, 2. Nivoslider.js, 3. jquery.prettyPhoto.js, 4. jquery.tools.min.js

Comment: Ok, so what doesn't work? how does it not work? what does `does not work` mean in this case? we can't see what you see. help us help you.

Comment: Sorry! I didnt pay atention on the order you gived to me! now i did as you indicated, and it worked! Thank you! THE PROBLEMS WAS IN THE ORDER