# jQuery jquery.tools.min and jquery.min cannot work in same page (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my Bootstrap page I used jquery.tools.min.js for navigation drop-down and  jquery.min.js for a model box which display image by its id.

If I used jquery.min.js, Model box work well but navigation not work.

I used jquery.tools.min.js in navigation.php file, So all of my page got it at first. And I have many many content with jquery.tools.min.js.

Now how put those all file together.

My code:

```html
<button class="light btn btn-info btn-responsive" id="http://myimage1.jpg">Display</button>

<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.light').click(function(){
            var src = $(this).attr('id');
            var img = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive"/>';
            $('#myModal').modal();
            $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
                $('#myModal .modal-body').html(img);
            });
           $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
                $('#myModal .modal-body').html('');
            });
        });  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: decuplicated question!!!!! pls use google (or any other seach engine) before ask!!!!

Comment: this is one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408752/jquery-conflict-with-jquery-tools , and googling will find hundreds of other similar questions

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `jquery.js` *before* `jquery.tools.js`:

> If you prefer to load the jQuery library separately the recommended practice is to load jQuery from Google's CDN service. Make sure the jQuery library is always loaded before the jQuery Tools library.

http://jquerytools.github.io/download/

Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Problem is I used jquery.tools.min.js in navigation.php file, So all of my page got it at first. And I have many many content with jquery.tools.min.js. Have any others way to do it.

Comment: How you achieve it will be down to your implementation, however the `jquery.js` file ***must*** be included in the page first.

Comment: Its not working, also remove jquery.tools.min.js from navigation page. As per your code only model box working only.

Answer (score 0):

Always you need to jquery link first after that you can include rest of link...

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```